# Checking irreducibility of polynomials in two variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

There are a few exercises in Hartshorne about checking singularity of an affine curve. For example, $Y$ defined by $x^2 = x^4 + y^4$ over a field $k$ (with ${\mathrm{char}}k \neq 2$). This is easy.

However, I was wondering how easy it is to prove that it is a curve; or equivalently $f(x,y) = x^4 + y^4 - x^2$ is irreducible.

Comment: I think a version of Eisenstein works. Treat it as a polynomial in $R[y]$ with $R=k[x]$ and note that $x-1$ is a prime in $R$ that does not divide the leading coefficient, divides all the others, and does not divide the constant term $x^{4}-x^{2}$ twice. Admittedly, I don't know a good reference for this "version" of Eisenstein; I must have picked it up somewhere but all the references I find make specific reference to integers and rationals, for some reason.

Comment: This is perfect Will. You are using Gauss' lemma there as well. :)

Comment: @WillR In case you care about having a place to point to in the future, I checked Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter* $\it 0$ and he states Eisenstein for general commutative rings. The same proof works as well; the only fact you actually use is that modding out by a prime ideal results in an integral domain.

Comment: @TabesBridges: Thank you! Of course, I expected the same proof to work; that's why I was so surprised that my (admittedly not very thorough) search only turned up references to polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out (Sorry to bother). If it is reducible then we have two choices:

(1) $y^4 + x^4 - x^2 = (y + f(x))(y^3 + g_2(x)y^2 + g_1(x)y + g_0(x))$. In this case either $f(x) = 0$ or $g_0(x) = 0$. Neither is possible as the polynomial is not in the ideal $\langle y \rangle$.

(2) $y^4 + x^4 - x^2 = (y^2 + f_1(x)y + f_0(x))(y^2 + g_1(x)y + g_0(x))$. Here comparing the terms either $f_1(x) = 0$ or $f_0(x) = 0$. In the first case $g_1(x) = 0 = g_0(x)$. In the second case $f_1(x) = 0$. None of them are possible as the polynomial is not in the ideal $\langle y^2 \rangle$.